# Why does the following htacces directive not work as expected?

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

I have the following redirects:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}  ^/index\.php$
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^id=409$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.domain.eu/index.php\?id=4 [R=301,L]


RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} foo_Bar\.pdf$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.domain.eu/index.php\?id=4 [R=301,L]
```

The first one works fine.
But the second one is not directing, when I open this url: `domain.eu/fileadmin/images/foo_Bar.pdf` (showing an 404 instead, thats why I want to redirect).

I've also tried to add a `^(.*)` before the filename, but it doesnt work either. I've even tried to enter full url as the request uri, no luck. What am I missing?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will redirect `www.yourdomain.com/index.php?id=409` to `http://www.domain.eu/index.php?id=4`

And the second will redirect if your site address ends with `.foo_Bar.pdf` redirects to `http://www.domain.eu/index.php?id=4`

You need to change the second one to:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} foo_Bar\.pdf$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.domain.eu/index.php\?id=4 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: sorry that was a typo, still doesnt work like that. appreciate your help

Comment: @Alex you're still scaping the `_` which is not needed and may be causing the issue.

Comment: another typo... my bad |: have tried so many versions, sorry. still does not work. what else could it be?

Comment: @Alex Well then you have something else blocking the rule because I have just tried it on my own domain and it works as expected you should review your others rules.

Comment: i was afraid of that... the weird thing is that all the other rules work perfectly and update immediately... so weird

Comment: Your browser could have cached the redirect which is a plague to be honest. @Alex if you have another browser and haven't used it on the site try it out.

Comment: definitely not a caching issue

Comment: @Alex try commenting all your rules and enabling 1 by 1 to see which causes your pdf redirect to fail then.

Comment: it worked when i put it to the top of the document... kinda weird because i dont see any line which could disable this to work. also, the other redirects to work. thanks anyway

Comment: @Alex you're welcome, perhaps you have some rule which considers only the start of the `%{REQUEST_URI}` and by coincidence the file falls into of of those folders it was matching ? just an idea ;)